# Emacs Lisp, programatically narrow down key bindings

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

Solved! helm-descbinds solved the problem.

https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm-descbinds

Thank you for your help.

---

I was trying to work out if I could build a simple script to narrow down key bindings, somewhat similar to IDO. I know of Icicle, but for some reason I didn't like it.

During my search I ran into many problems and beging to think that the only way out is to run:

```
(describe-bindings)
```

and then try to parse *Help* buffer.

Is there a way to get pre-parsed flat list of biding? I got lost trying to understand the keymap structure.

I guess recursively parsing the keymap structure is too much work. Is there a simple solution?

This is example of my early progress.

https://github.com/bigos/Pyrulis/blob/master/Emacs/key-bindings-lister/lisp/key-bindings-lister.el

After a while of trying, looks like getting the info from *Help* buffer didnt work. I got some strange structures with the string and when I tried to use print, it didn't print what I wanted.  Perhaps I will have to parse the keymap?

After playing with keymap for a while, I think this is the way to go. More in my github link.

My last attempt.

```
;;; run in ielm like this: (my-list-bindings 11)
;;; n=11 for global
(defun my-list-bindings (n)
  "almost clean way of listing key bindings"
  (map-keymap
   (lambda (x y)
     (print "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
     (princ x)
     (if (eq x 'menu-bar)
         (print "*** skipping menu bar ***")
       (print y)))
   (elt (current-active-maps) n )))
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "narrow down"?

Comment: `M-x describe-bindings` will show you all bindings. C-h m `(M-x describe-mode)` is also handy to list bindings by mode.

Comment: *descibe-bindings* gives me many thousands of bindings that I'm not interested at the moment. I wonder if there's a better way to search than using C-s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to see what key bindings are available at any instant in time.

In that case, try [helm-descbinds](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm-descbinds), which works with [helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm). Key bindings are organized by major mode, minor modes, and the global map. You can then use a regular expression to narrow down your choice, e.g. `^C-x\ [a-z]` to find all bindings that begin with `C-x` and are followed by a letter from `a-z`.

You can also try [discover-my-major](https://github.com/steckerhalter/discover-my-major), which lists all the key bindings of your current major mode, along with an `apropos`-like description of what they do. I find that it is useful when I'm trying to learn a new major mode.